# Android Studio Memory Usage

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

I'm developing an app in Flutter and I'm writing the code in Android Studio. However it doesnt take long before the memory usage of the IDE passes 3GB. Sometimes it even goes above 4GB. There have been times when memory usage is closer to 6.5GB This is when I'm not even running the app in the emulator or on a device. The emulator isn't even running.

The machine I'm using has a total of 16GB of RAM, but Android Studio still manages to slow everything down. If I go into the Memory Settings and change the `Maximum Heap Size` to a higher value, nothing changes. No matter what I set the value to, the next time I check the Memory settings, the value is back at 1920MB. Please see image below.

[image]

So I tried moving to IntelliJ IDEA. But it's the same thing there. No matter what I set the Memory Settings to, everyrhing slows down within 10 minutes. In IntelliJ IDEA, I even tried turing `Power Save Mode` but that only seemed to make it run out of memory even faster?

I just thinks is totaly unresonable for a program to use that much memory.

Is there any way of solving this, or will I have to move over to Visual Studio Code, or something similar?

Comment: That's "normal" for IntelliJ-based IDE. You'll have to use VS Code or other less fully-featured IDE

Comment: Yeah it seems like this is the way to go.

Comment: Please report an issue on YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) attaching logs folder for investigation (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)